# Django: Create connection between old and new application model

Tags: django, model

**The situation:**

I have a database with thousands of users.

I have created a new application called '**my_app**'.

**my_app** has one object called '**my_Object**'.

**my_object** has an a relation **one_to_one** with the Django User.

```
class my_object(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

**My question is:**

How can I create a register for all users already on the database? I know I can use post_save for the new ones, but how can I relate / connect this new object backwards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a SQL query in your favorite database manager that creates records for all the existing `User` records.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But I was wondering if there is any kind of signal or process executed when adding applications.

Comment: You don't need a signal. It only needs to be run once, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing from MySql you could also do it from the `django shell`. Access all the records from the old user base as a query list and then create a `my_object` for them. As answered above there is no need for setting the signal, as the task has to be done only once. Also such an app based signal, if possible would be more cumbersome to do.

```
old_users = Old_users.objects.all() for user in old_users:
    object = my_object(user = user)
    object.save()
```

By the way, how have you added the old users to `django user`?